# Como inserir um dado Fixo no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Boa tarde, tudo bem?
Estou trabalhando em um sistema multi usuario
Onde a maioria das tabelas possuem um store_id
esse campo viria da session onde armazeno na hora do login do usuario o id da loja dele.
Entao quando ele for cadastrar uma categoria por exemplo eu gostaria de nao ter de passar o store_id na hora da insercao do registro, gostaria de saber se isso e possivel, na minha modela esta dessa maneira:

```
protected $fillable = [
    'store_id',
    'nameCategory',
    'positionCategory',
];
```

Ja na controller na hora de inserir os dados eu preciso inserir o store_id, e gostaria de passar apenas os campos necessarios

```
public function store(CategoryRequest $request)
{
    $category = $this->categoryRepository->store([
        'nameCategory'                  => $request->nameCategory,
        'positionCategory'              => $request->positionCategory,
    ]);

    dd($category);
}
```

Tenho tambem uma trait que tentei fazer mas nao ajudou, pois quando mando create ele nao guarda.

```
trait Storable
```

{
protected static function bootStorable(){

```
    static::addGlobalScope(new StoreScope);

    if(checkStoreID()){
        static::creating(function($model)
        {
            $model->store_id = session()->get('store_id');
        });
    }
}

public function store(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Store::class);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Resolvi da seguinte Maneira:
Criei um Observer e dentro do Observer Coloquei o Codigo:

```
 /*#############################################################################################################    
# FUNCAO...: creating | AUTOR......: Jeanderson Rodrigues | DATA.......: 04/07/2023                                     
# DESCRICAO..: Funcao para adicionar automaticamente o ID da Store ao Incluir um registro
###############################################################################################################*/   
public function creating(Model $model){
    if(checkStoreID()){
        $store_id = session()->get('store_id');
        $model->setAttribute('store_id',$store_id);
    }
}
```

Apos isso, instanciei ele na minha trait

```
static::observe(new StoreObserver);
```

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).